# Why for the sequence in a Hilbert space to be convergent we need the given sequence to be weakly convergent?

Tags: functional-analysis

Why do we need a weak convergence for the sequence in a Hilbert space to be convergent?
A Hilbert space is a complete pre-Hilbert space, so, every sequence converges in a given space.

Where is my confusion?
Many thanks.

Comment: Weak convergence and convergence are not the same for a Hilbert space. For example, if $\{ e_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal set of vectors, then this sequence converges weakly to 0, but it doesn't converge in norm because $\|e_{n}-e_{m}\|=\sqrt{2}$ for $n\ne m$.

Comment: I don't know if maybe he is asking why 'convergent implies weakly convergent'...?

Comment: I can't tell precisely what is meant by the question, especially "every sequence converges in a given space."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strong convergence implies weak convergence.

Proof: if $x_n\to x$ then

$$
\langle x_n, y \rangle - \langle x, y \rangle
=\langle x_n-x, y \rangle\\
|\langle x_n-x, y \rangle|\le |x_n-x||y|\to 0
$$

Anyway, the other implication if false:
consider $x_n = 1_{[n,n+1]}\in L^2(\Bbb R)$.